# ¿Porqué al importar un archivo .csv a R los elementos del Tibble salen todos NA?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, ciencia-de-datos, tibble

Necesito un alma altruista y desinteresada que me ayude con un problemilla que tengo al tratar de importar datos desde un archivo .csv a R, ya intente con re`ad.table(file.choose(),sep = "\t")`, y con `read_csv( )` pero mi problema es que los elementos de mi tibble salen  todos NA , alguien tiene alguna idea de que pasa, adjunto imagen en el formato en el que están los datos(separados con tabulador)...

[image: Elementos en el archivo .csv , como se puede observar pareciera que estan separados por tab]

Ejemplo:

```
NO. Hora Intervalo Temperatura Interna(°C) Humedad Interna(%) Temperatura Externa(°C) Humedad Externa(%) Presión Relativa(hpa) Presión Absoluta(hpa) Velocidad del viento(km/h) Ráfaga(km/h) Dirección del viento Punto de Rocío(°C) 
22/09/2018 9:41:40 p. m. 5 17.2 60 10.7 99 1013.3
```

Comment: Bienvenido Diego Andres Burgos a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Te sugiero que agregues una muestra aunque sea pequeña del archivo a importar. Por otro lado, prueba con la función base: `read.csv(file=file.choose(),sep = "\t", header=TRUE)` y en particular fijate si obtienes algún error o warning y agregalo a tu pregunta. Suerte.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho gracias por tu respuesta y la sugerencia, intente ya anteriormente con el código que mencionaste, y arroja el siguiente mensaje: **line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls**, igual con la linea 2, 3 etc.. con respecto al contenido del  archivo a importar .csv aquí esta una parte `NO. Hora Intervalo Temperatura Interna(°C) Humedad Interna(%) Temperatura Externa(°C) Humedad Externa(%) Presión Relativa(hpa) Presión Absoluta(hpa) Velocidad del viento(km/h) Ráfaga(km/h) Dirección del viento Punto de Rocío(°C) 22/09/2018 9:41:40 p. m.  5  17.2  60  10.7  99  1013.3 `

Comment: Prueba hacer `read.table(file=file.choose(),sep = "\t", header=TRUE, skipNul = TRUE)`, a ver si funciona.

Comment: BRILLANTE!  GRACIAS.

Comment: Me alegro, escribí la respuesta para que sirva a futuro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por el error que tienes, puede ocurrir dos cosas:

1. El `encoding` es incorrecto, en cuyo caso deberías establecer al leer, la misma codificación que se usó al escribir el archivo. Por ejemplo:

   ```
   read.table(file=file.choose(),sep = "\t",header=TRUE,fileEncoding="UTF8")
   ```
2. El archivo contiene caracteres nulos (`char(0)`), en cuyo caso puedes usar el parámetro `SkipNul`, por ejemplo:

   ```
   read.table(file=file.choose(),sep = "\t", header=TRUE,skipNul = TRUE)
   ```